# Getting values of all important exchanges around the world

Tags: java, yahoo, yahoo-finance

I would like to know if there is some way to access the values of the exchanges(important ones like nasdaq, Bse, nse ,dowjones,japanese and asian markets). I know about yahoo finance but am unsure of how exactly to get a list of all exchanges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google it - example: http://www.world-exchanges.org/.  If I were you I would try rss feeds - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZ8mhOoRK7I.

Hope it helps.

Comment: guess i was not clear enough in my question. I want to access the values from java in my program. In world exchanges.org i did not find any way to access the value of the indices around the world, And in the video you posted too. I want to get the value of important exchanges from my java program.

Comment: you go to http://www.world-exchanges.org/member-exchanges and you have a map of all the exchanges that are members and for each of them you can check values of the current exchange (e.g. http://www.nasdaq.com/ and then http://www.nasdaq.com/quotes/real-time.aspx).  It is up to you how you will transfer them into your java app (I think rss feeds are best).

Comment: I am having to click on the map to get the value of that particular exchange. This will make it very difficult to get data from any html parser(the exchange value also does not show the price. Only market cap and other data is shown). I did not see any rss feed on this ite. How would i go about getting the data from this website and does the website permit this. Would you know of any other site which provides this service

Comment: It is only a starting point - you can view the member exchanges from there.  Then you need to go to each particular member exchange website and get the data you need as in the example provided - http://www.nasdaq.com/quotes/real-time.aspx - you can see prices here.  More about rss feeds (for this particular website) here - http://www.nasdaq.com/services/rss.aspx.  You can have something like this - http://www.nasdaq.com/aspxcontent/NasdaqRSS.aspx?data=uvup and process it.  Do your job and check other websites on your own